# Are there risks of manuscript rejection if manuscript is the edited version of a thesis report available online?

Tags: publications, thesis, ieee

I have completed a thesis project report that is currently uploaded in ResearchGate with a DOI identifier. Out of that report, I created a manuscript for publication in IEEE and recently submitted my manuscript.

My question is this: how would IEEE determine that I am not plagiarizing and that the manuscript that I recently submitted is just from my own thesis project report that I uploaded in ResearchGate. Are there any risks?

Comment: Doesn't your thesis have your name on it?

Comment: Yes, it does. I just want to make sure there are no risks.

Comment: Most publishers have policies that permit publication of journal papers that are based on theses and dissertations, but this can vary from publisher to publisher.  You should check IEEE's policy on prior publication and see what they have to say about theses.

Comment: Perhaps IEEE can answer this better than we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this policy statement](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6279469) we have the following quote:

> **Technical Reports, Dissertations, and Lectures:** Internal
> reports and memos distributed within an institution, lecture
> notes, tutorials, seminars, and academic theses or dissertations
> are not considered prepublication even if available online

and [according to MIT's resources page](https://libraries.mit.edu/scholarly/publishing/theses-copyright/theses-and-article-publishing/) (see subsection on IEEE):

> **Submission of new article by author that first appeared as part of author’s thesis**
>
> Theses not specifically addressed, but permitted subject to editorial discretion. Individual journals may have their own policies

From these two quotes, it seems that if the publication is allowed at all, then you won't have any problem with having put it online previously because IEEE doesn't consider that prepublishing. However, individual journals may not accept theses for publication.

The answer to "how would IEEE determine that I am not plagiarizing" specifically is simply "both have your name on them."